# Label sums of surfaces grouped by common attribute values

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, labeling, aggregation, summarizing

I want to label the sums of surfaces (`"Groesse"`) grouped by common attribute values (`"Block"`) in QGIS 3.16. I need **one label for each group**.
The following pictures help to describe the expected result.

Here is an example of my attribute table:

[image]

Here is the result I want to get. 5 sums grouped by the `"Block"` column are represented below: 3 orange (D1, D2 and D3), 1 grey (S1) and 1 green (G1)

[image]

- I thought to create a virtual layer with a function that sum the surfaces (`"Groesse"`) per attribute value(`"Block"`). Despite my attempts, I do not know how to write it correctly in SQL (sum(`"Groesse"`,`"Block"`) in Python).
- I also tried to display labels through a Rule-based expression in using the aggregate function, without success.

Comment: What software do you use?

Comment: Qgis 3.16. You're right I just changed the title of my question. Thx

Comment: You can use DB Manage to create virtual layer using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'LayerB'* with it's corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to create one label for each group.*

```sql
SELECT st_union(geometry) AS geom,
       SUM("Value") AS sum_v,
       COUNT(*) AS count_f
FROM "LayerB"
GROUP BY "group"
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like

[image: result]

*where*

- `"sum_v"` shows the summed values for grouped features
- `"count_f"` represents how many features were grouped

And afterwards apply  for a Virtual Layer a common labeling.

Comment: This is also very interesting that way, thank you. However, the categorized representation of the polygons following the "count_f" is not right. For an unknown reason, surfaces counted in the "count_if" fields sum too many polygons at once (for instance D1 + D2, D4 + D7). Therefore, too few groups are created. A workound is to also symbolize polygons per category following the "sum_v" values.

Comment: Strange that this happens, maybe simply skip the `"count_f"`-field. BTW, is the geometry congruent?

Comment: Geometry is not congruent in this case.
But now I find out where lies the problem. The SQL query is right, the categorized representation of the `"count_f"` field may render it wrongly in some cases: 
the `COUNT(*) AS count_f` line counts how many values are in the "Block" field. Yet, when there is same counted values (for example, 2 times "7" in `"count_f"` field), then the categorized symbology consider them identical, and represent them with the same color, although the `st_union(geometry)` worked well. Therefore a categorized representation with the `"sum_v"` is right.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'LayerB'* with it's corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

First of all duplicate your layer via `RMC > Duplicate...`

Then proceed with `RMC > Layer Properties > Symbology > Single Symbol > Geometry Generator`.

In the field for the [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) paste the following expression

```py
buffer(collect($geometry, group_by:="group"), 0)
```

[image: geom_generator]

Then in `Label with` field apply the following expression

```py
sum("Value", group_by:="group")
```

And then for `Placement` (via Coordinate Edit) use

```py
X | x(centroid(buffer(collect($geometry, group_by:="group"), 0)))
Y | y(centroid(buffer(collect($geometry, group_by:="group"), 0)))
```

[image: labelling_rules]

And get the output

[image: result]

Comment: Even if I preferred the accepted solution, this one worked too.

Comment: You dont really need to duplicate the layer (but it could be easier to manage your project with two separate layer)

Comment: You are correct @J.R !

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'LayerB'* with it's corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html#dissolve) the original layer via the grouping field, in my case it is `"group"`

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** For the dissolved layer use the following expression for labeling

```py
aggregate(
      layer:='LayerB',
      aggregate:='sum',
      expression:="Value",
      filter:=intersects(centroid($geometry), geometry(@parent))
    )
```

[image: step2]

Comment: This solution is working as long as you do not change the size of the original polygons, which won't be my case unfortunately.

Comment: okay I did not know that =) This is more a one-time solution rather than continuous.